# ASP.NET Url encode - url action > Doesnt go to the right controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having a little trouble with the `Url.Encode` method.

I'm trying to create my menu with this Url.encode(Url.Action(..)). Everything is fine unless I want to go to a different controller ( Eg from account controller to my home controller ).

Here is the menu

```
<ul>
                        <li id="Home"><a href="@Url.Encode(Url.Action("Index","Home"))">Home</a></li>
                        <li id="About"><a href="@Url.Encode(Url.Action("About","Home"))">About</a></li>
                        <li id="Tickets"><a href="@Url.Encode(Url.Action("Tickets","Home"))">Tickets</a></li>
                        <li id="Events"><a href="@Url.Encode(Url.Action("Events","Home"))">Events</a></li>
                    </ul>   
                    <!--<ul>
                        <li id="Home">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li id="About">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li id="Tickets">@Html.ActionLink("Tickets", "Tickets", "Home")</li>
                        <li id="Events">@Html.ActionLink("Events", "Events", "Home")</li>

                    </ul>-->
```

The menu in comment is the menu i used before the Url.Encode.

If i'm at home and i go for example to 'About' I get this link :

```
> http://localhost:1211/%2fHome%2fAbout
```

However if i'm at my account controller and want to go the same page this is the result :

```
> http://localhost:1211/Account/%2fHome%2fAbout
```

You can see it still puts up the /Account/ infront of this. How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of `Url.Encode()` is to encode a string so that it can be inserted into a URL, without treating any special characters in the string as URL characters.

That's exactly the opposite of what you want here.

Comment: So i shouldnt encode this? Guess i got confused by our theory slide. Sorry for the inconvience.

Comment: @Mathieu: You need to encode whenever you concatenate data into a structured language.  Here, you need to HTML-encode.  However, Razor does that for you.

Comment: Okay. Thanks very much! I'll look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a RouteOptions :

@Url.Action("Index", new {controller = "Home"})